# Error when calling ClassPathResource.getInputStream()

Tags: java, spring

i want so study Spring,i start from hello World

I learned to make a hello world from this address "[http://javacpplus.blogspot.com/2012/04/spring-framework-with-netbeans-70.html[url=http://http://javacpplus.blogspot.com/2012/04/spring-framework-with-netbeans-70.html]webpage[/url]](http://javacpplus.blogspot.com/2012/04/spring-framework-with-netbeans-70.html%5burl=http://http://javacpplus.blogspot.com/2012/04/spring-framework-with-netbeans-70.html%5dwebpage%5b/url%5d)"

And this is my code, i make two class. 1 HelloWorld.java And 2 MainApp.java 
  and i Make one xml that is Beans.xml

check this is out
   class HelloWorld.java

```
package com.hello;

/**  *  * @author bobfuad  */ public class HelloWorld {
    private String message;

   public void setMessage(String message){
      this.message  = message;    }

   public void getMessage(){
      System.out.println("Your Message : " + message);    } }
```

class MainApp.java

```
package com.hello;

mport org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;
/**
 *
 * @author bobfuad
 */
public class MainApp {
    private static Resource ClassPathApplicationContext;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
      ApplicationContext context;
        context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("Beans.xml");

      HelloWorld obj = (HelloWorld) context.getBean("helloWorld");

      obj.getMessage();
   }
}
```

Beans.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"

       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
">
<bean id="helloWorld" class="com.hello.HelloWorld">
       <property name="message" value="Hello World!"/>
   </bean>
</beans>
```

that it's my code, but when i run this program, there is have problem

and this is problem

```
Jun 27, 2014 8:48:44 AM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@e3849c: startup date [Fri Jun 27 08:48:44 PDT 2014]; root of context hierarchy
Jun 27, 2014 8:48:44 AM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [Beans.xml]
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from class path resource [Beans.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [Beans.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:341)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:174)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:209)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:180)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:243)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:127)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:93)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:130)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:451)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at com.hello.MainApp.main(MainApp.java:18)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [Beans.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:157)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:328)
    ... 13 more
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

please help me, thanks

Comment: Please provide a more useful title

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like the error message says, Beans.xml is not found in your classpath (in the given path, i.e. root). If you have placed the file next to the Java classes in `com/hello`, then use the path `com/hello/Beans.xml` in your main method.